# The program is not opening to me a shell

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
        FILE *fp = fopen("1.pass", "r");
        struct {char pass[20], msg_err[20];} pwfile = {{0}};
        char ptr[0];

        if(!fp || argc != 2)
                return -1;

        fread(pwfile.pass, 1, 20, fp);
        pwfile.pass[19] = 0;
        ptr[atoi(argv[1])] = 0;
        fread(pwfile.msg_err, 1, 19, fp);
        fclose(fp);

        if(!strcmp(pwfile.pass, argv[1])) {
                setuid(0);
                execl("/bin/sh", "sh", 0);
       } else
                puts(pwfile.msg_err);

        return 0;
}
```

Hello there. 
I give on input to the program a password. The program checks this password, which is in `1.pass`. If all is correct - opens to me a shell, if it not correct - print `ACCESS DENIED`.
In my cases, it didn't open shell up to me, I don't know why. Any ideas what I missed?

Comment: I expect this to happen: https://i.imgur.com/Uzahh94.png

Comment: sh is just a link to bash on my system

Comment: Use `strace -Ff your-program` to verify what it does. Maybe the exec produces an error message that you did not spot?

Comment: Try using a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

```
char ptr[0];
ptr[atoi(argv[1])] = 0;
```

This is not legal C++, as there are no zero sized arrays in C++. Even if some C++ compilers offer zero sized arrays as an extension, this particular code doesn't do anything useful, and may or may not format your hard disk.

Comment: As a side note, if you are using C++, use proper idiomatic C++. C code is better handled by C compilers